# Angular 2: Using a component in two diffrent ways: as target of a route and by selector <selector-my-component>

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

This is a general question concerning Angular 2 (no source code here)

In Angular2 components can be assigned as the target of a specific route of the router. The route

```
/something/:myId
```

might activate the "SomethingComponent".

Meanwhile components can be pulled into other components by referencing the selector in the template like this:

```
<something-component [myId]="'123'"></something-component>
```

Is it ok to use one component in both ways? Can I distinguish within the component, how it was activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the `Router` like

```
constructor(@Optional() private router:Router) {}
```

As far as I remember if it is not a routed component the router won't be injected.

You could also add an `@Input() someName` and use it like `<some-dual [someName]="someValue">`. Inputs aren't set when the component is added by the router.

You could also use a wrapper element that doesn't do anything but wrapping the component, and forwarding bindings so that they are set in `<some-dual>` the same way as when added by the router (for example by a shared service instead of bindings) and the wrapper could set an additional flag that indicates that the component was instantiated from a template instead of from the router.