# Using Angular 2 Component in both Tabs and Views

Tags: angular, routes

Assume there are a few `Angular 2` components

- `SearchComponent`
- `SearchResultComponent`
- `DetailsComponent`

The SearchComponent allows the user to enter criteria, execute the search (using `SearchService`), and loops through the results rendering each result with a `SearchResultComponent`. Pretty standard stuff.

The `SearchResultComponent` renders some results data along with an anchor tag containing `routerLink` with the route (for example, `/article/details/1234`) configured to replace the current view with `DetailsComponent`.

Again, this is all typical and works as expected.

The dilemma is that based on a user setting (i.e. user profile), I would like the `SearchComponent` to be able to render the search form and results in a single tab and then each time they click the details link for a given result an instance of the `DetailsComponent` opens in a new tab. Alternatively, if the user has the profile setting cleared, the originally described behavior is in effect -- clicking the anchor link results in `Angular 2 Routing` replacing the current view.

I already figured out, and have confirmed via https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945055/240372, that the `DetailsComponent` can be coded so that it handles being loaded from both routing parameters and attribute/model binding parameters.

My **guess** is around the condition of sometimes rendering content in tabs and sometimes letting Angular routing handle it. My guess is that the `SearchComponent` would need to have a reference to a `ProfileComponent` that contains the users setting so it could conditionally render the tab or not. But if `SearchResultComponent` is rendering an anchor tag with a `routerLink` attribute, how would the parent `SearchComponent` know to **not** allow routing to kick in?

Instead it would need to somehow intercept that click, grab the routing parameters, create a new tab with a `DetailsComponent` as the content while passing in the parameters as attribute values.

In my mind, the SearchResultComponent should be **ignorant** that the result of click event is being rendered in a tab versus replacing the current view.

**Adding code snippets for clarification**

If I was building a plain old `jquery` site, my "`SearchComponent`" and "`SearchResultComponent`" output may look *something* (not real code...just for conceptual purposes) like

```
<!-- rendered by Search Component -->
<div>
   <div class='searchForm'>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms or phase" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class='searchResults'>
      <ul>
         <!-- rendered by Search Results Component -- one li for each result -->
         <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/27'>Go read 27</a>
         <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/3'>Go read 3</a>
         <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/43543'>Go read 43543</a>
         ...
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now in **non-tabs** mode, when a user click on the "Go read" link, the page would navigate away from the current page.

However, in **tabs** mode, the output would *almost* be the same except for a little extra stuff outputted by the "SearchComponent".

```
<!-- rendered by Search Component -->
<div class="tabs">
   <div class="tab">
      <h3>Search Tab</h3>
      <div>
         <div class='searchForm'>
            <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms or phase" />
              <input type="submit" />
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class='searchResults'>
            <ul>
               <!-- rendered by Search Results Component -- one li for each result -->
               <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/27'>Go read 27</a>
               <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/3'>Go read 3</a>
               <li>blah blah blah <a href='/details/43543'>Go read 43543</a>
               ...
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   $('.searchResults a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();      // so page does not navigate away
      // add new tab
      var tab = tabs.add();
      // load content
      tab.loadContent($(this).attrib('href'));
    });
</script>
```

In both cases, the  element outputted by the "`SearchResultComponent`" is the same since it is ignorant of tab vs non-tab mode. It is the **parent** component/module/whatever that intercepts the click event to ultimately create the tab and put the content that *would* have replaced the page into a tabbed view.

The **equivalent** Angular 2 markup would be something like

```
<!-- rendered by Search Component -->
<searchComponent>
   <div class='searchForm'>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms or phase" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class='searchResults'>
      <ul>
         <searchResult *ngFor='let item of results' [result]='item'></searchResult>
         <!-- where SearchResultComponent would output the equivalent for each item in results array -->
         <li>blah blah blah <a [routerLink]="['/details', result.id]">Go read 27</a>
         ...
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Like before, the `SearchComponent` would be knowledgeable of tabs vs non-tabs mode and would output the appropriate templates.

And like before, the `SearchComponent` would need to do the **ng2 equivalent** of listening for  click events for `routerLink` so the navigation can be intercepted and the output put into a tab instead of replacing current view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but if I do you need to do:

```
onUserEvent()
{
  this.isLazyRender = ProfileService.IsLazyRender;
  if(isLazyRender){
     this.router.navigate(['/article/details/1234']);
  else{
     this.showDetailsComponent = true;
  }
}
```

if you want the search result to be ignorant to the binding you should use a service to handle the data

Comment: Avi -- I do not think you quite understood what I meant. The original post has been updated with code snippets for clarification.

Comment: what I meant be my code snippet is that you don't need the anchor tag with the routerLink. instead call onUserEvent that will make the decision which way to go.

Comment: Add your suggestion is to put that code snippet where? In the SearchComponent or the SearchResultsComponent? Putting it in the SearchResultsComponent means that the SearchResultsComponent needs to have a coupling to the Profile Component which I am trying to avoid. Putting the snippet in the SearchComponent means that the Results Component is now dependent on the Search Component to be userful. Not sure I like either choice... Please clarify. Thank you.

Comment: The profile should be a service that can be injected to whatever component that needs it, no coupling involved. You put a lot of information on your post and I can only understand the general idea so my answer will be abit more general. you should put my code snippet at the point you want different behavior. if this is going to be on search component then yes, you should analyze your profile service and decide if you want to route to searchResultComponentA(which gives you scenario A) or SearchResultComponertB(which gives you scenario B) or embed the SearchResultCompoennt in searchComponent.